# Transparency on Imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick, transparency, opacity, imagemagick-convert

I'm using this code wrote on ImageMagick, but I want this background:

[image: Img 1]

In order to match the color of my terminal, which is `#000` with 70% opacity. If I leave it without background, it just goes completely transparent:

[image: Img 2]

And no matter what I do, it doesn't works or it makes the image missing. I've searched through the ImageMagick code on forums and here on StackOverflow, but I couldnt make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ImageMagick, to get #000 or black or rgb(0,0,0) with 70% opacity, use

```
"rgba(0,0,0,0.7)"
```

or the closest hex value would be

```
#000000b3
```

So your convert command should be:

```
convert input.suffix -resize 300x -gravity center -background "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)" -extent 1100x400 output.png
```

Do not save to JPG, since it does not support transparency.

Keep the quotes if on a Unix-like system or if you put spaces between the commas.

Comment: If you are saving to JPG, it does not support transparency. You need to save to PNG or TIFF

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform? You can get the version from `convert -version` if on ImageMagick 6 and from `magick -version` if on ImageMagick 7.

Comment: It is always best to test code by trying just the convert command by itself with actual image files for input and output.